# Netbeans regenerates broken code in TopComponent. How do I fix this?

Tags: java, netbeans, compiler-generated

I've been dealing with this for over a week, and now it's beginning to impede my productivity.

I have a JTextBox that I am applying a custom document filter to. To add this, I right-clicked on the control, went into Customize Code, and added this line beneath everything:

```
 ((javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument)jtfTextField.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new mylibrary.NumericDocumentFilter());
```

Now, this was a copy-paste job (as I've used this in other places). The field I wanted to set the filter to is called `TextField`. By mistake, I clicked OK, compiled, and it exploded. Duh, I see my mistake. I fix it, recompile, and I still get the error. Now my code has this:

```
 ((javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument)TextField.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new mylibrary.NumericDocumentFilter());
 ((javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument)jtfTextField.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new mylibrary.NumericDocumentFilter());
```

And when I go into Customize Code, it just shows the correct (top) one. I close Netbeans, edit the file with Notepad++ and remove the offending line, and start Netbeans back up. Now it compiles, I run it, test, then when I go back, the code regenerated itself with the erroneous line.

I blew out the cache for Netbeans and that did nothing, so I am really at a loss on how to fix this. Any takers?

Netbeans Version 7.3.1.

**Update:** I snoop'd around a bit and found this in my Topcomponent's *.form file:

```
<AuxValues>
    <AuxValue name="JavaCodeGenerator_AddingCodePost" type="java.lang.String" value="((javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument)jtfTextField.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new mylibrary.NumericDocumentFilter());"/>
</AuxValues>
```

Perhaps deleting this could fix the issue, but I'm not sure, and really don't want to risk destroying this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try cleaning and rebuilding your project (Shift + F11 by default). If this will not regenerate the form and the error still persists:
2. Edit the form: replace code in `value` property of the tag above by your code.

As for the error itself, you should put only *generated* code in the generated section. You can always do post-init after the `initComponents()` method in the constructor. This avoids possible errors in GUI Editor and eases the control of the code for you.

Comment: Looks like option 2 did it. I always thought that using "Customize Code" would make the code look cleaner, since it would encapsulate all the properties right there, but I think for now on I'll stick to making an `initCustomComponents()` function. Thank you!